# How do I build a Gideros project for Android with Ant?

Tags: android, ant, build, gideros

That's it, actually. I prefer not to use Eclipse, and want to use the command line.

I've tried to just build it without doing anything special, but it gave me errors like:

```
package com.giderosmobile.android.player does not exist
cannot find symbol AudioDevice
 etc.
```

Also, if it's possible, I'd like to use another IDE and use the command line for the entire process. Is this possible? If yes, how?

This is my first question here on SO, so please correct me if I'm asking it wrong.

Comment: Can you link to this project? I will attempt to build it with ant... and see if I can't work through the issues on this end.

Comment: Sure, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3romr4owd4uqmi/Button.zip)'s an example project.

Comment: Check the posted answer. I will update it as I work you through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first, I noticed that there was no included ant build file, and it was missing several other things. So first things first...

```
{sdkdir}/tools/android update project --path [locationToProject]
```

Will generate your build files and everything else.

But it looks like from trying to build this failed because it wants to import location

```
com.giderosmobile.android.player.*
```

You might be missing that dependency or the package is named incorrectly...

**[Edit]**

I swapped this line:

```
import com.giderosmobile.android.player.*;
```

with

```
import com.giderosmobile.android.player.AudioDevice;
import com.giderosmobile.android.player.JavaNativeBridge;
```

And it built just fine using 'ant debug'. Hope that helps!

**[Edit 2]**

Move "gideros.jar" into the libs folder

Comment: This gives me the error `package com.giderosmobile.android.player does not exist` twice and the errors for not finding the classes trying to import. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, it works now! (Of course it also works with `import com.giderosmobile.android.player.*;` now.)

Comment: Yes, it should work with your default import. I didn't realize that I had moved that file, after I made my initial comment.